# Работа с массивами javascript

Tags: массивы, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток есть такая задача:
имеются 2 массива, в первом есть id `введите код здесь`товара, и всё что относится к нему(цвет товара, размер товара картинки и т.д.), а второй массив содержит название цвета и те id первого массива где данный цвет встречается, вот сам [код для примера](http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/QpKmH/)

Как сделать так чтобы при клике на картинки цветов пробегалось по первому массиву offers  и выводило только имеющиеся размеры данного цвета, то есть к примеру жму я на картинку цвета `Dark_Khaki` и мне должно вывести 2 размера `s` и `xl` так как в массиве `offers` есть два `id` с данным цветом это "25739" и "25737"? Если что-то не понятно пишите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае, если предположить, что `color` - это выбранный цвет, то

```
var ids = offersColor[color];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    alert(offers[ids[i]]);
}
```

Comment: у меня может быть с данным цветом в массиве несколько элементов, в данном случае их два

 "25739": ["18855","/upload/iblock/705/7059eda645bd01ecbc354dcce3a8189b.png","/upload/iblock/255/255667bb4266db1f3884403546b2a2b2.png","Dark_Khaki","s"],
    "25737": ["18855","/upload/iblock/705/7059eda645bd01ecbc354dcce3a8189b.png","/upload/iblock/255/255667bb4266db1f3884403546b2a2b2.png","Dark_Khaki","xl"],
и мне надо как то проходить по всему массиву offers и выводить все размеры данного цвета

Comment: Вам не надо проходить по всему массиву, ведь `offers` у вас не массив, а объект. Из него по ключу (который мы вытаскиваем, проходясь по массиву `offersColor[color]`) можно вытащить значение без итерации с поиском. Главное, чтобы в `offers` ключи были уникальными. Если ключи будут повторяться, то по ключу вернётся последний объект с указанным ключом.

Comment: как мне вывести только размеры s и xl  если нажать на картинку Dark_Khaki так как у этого цвета есть только 2 размера

Comment: Совсем уже люди обленились. Ваша задача была просто скопипастить мой код на место ваших вопросиков, добавив лишь определение цвета по id картинки, по которой кликнул пользователь. Как-то вроде `var color = $(this).attr('id')`. Дожили...

Comment: да ни чего я не обленился, я просто не догоняю как это должно работать, я счас сделал так http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/85kJ4/

тут при клике на цвет к примеру Dark_Khaki он выводит мне 2 id из массива offersColor, так вот мне надо чтобы както брало эти id и сравнивалось с данными offers и если находило такие же id то выводил размеры этих id

Comment: Под ленью я понимаю то, что вы используете объекты (или ассоциативные массивы, если угодно), но даже не пытаетесь понять, __что__ вы используете и как с этим работать. От желаемого результата вас отделяло всего немного: [http://jsfiddle.net/85kJ4/2/][1]

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/85kJ4/2/

Comment: Спасибо, я так и сделал, счас только мне надо выводить все размеры в список с размерами, при клике на первую картинку показывается только последний размер xl, а должен ещё быть и s можете глянуть http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/NEW6x/

Comment: Вам нужно сначала составить список размеров, а затем сверять id ссылки с этим списком: [http://jsfiddle.net/NEW6x/2/][1]

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/NEW6x/2/

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь onclick на все картинки с такой функцией:

```
function alertSize(nameColor){
  //получаем массив с id цветов
  var masId = offersColor[nameColor];
  for (var i in masId) {
    //4 - индекс массива
    alert(offers[i][4]);
  }
}
```

Код не проверял, но где то должно быть так.